# OCaml variant augmentation boilerplates

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, variant, ppx

Is there a way to efficiently "augment" or attach some more information without much boilerplate?

That is, given types

```ml
type orig =
  | A
  | B of orig
  | C of orig * orig
and type dat = int
and type aug =
  | AugA of dat
  | AugB of dat * aug
  | AugC of dat * aug * aug
```

and functions

```ml
let _cnt = ref 0
let gen_dat () =
  let _ = _cnt := !_cnt + 1 in
  !_cnt

let rec augment (o: orig) : ao =
  match o with
  | A -> AugA (gen_dat ())
  | B o -> AugB (gen_dat (), augment o)
  | C (o1, o2) -> AugC (gen_dat (), augment o1, augment o2)
```

I think this is a trivial structural recursion on its components, and I have to do repeat this type of identical manipulations on several types with 10+ patterns (Multiple `aug`s each with its own `augment` function associated).

This leads to a long, tedious boilerplate code. Is there a way to abstract away this manipulation in OCaml, e.g., with help of ppx?

Comment: It looks like maybe type `aug` might be defined as `type aug = Aug of int * orig`. While there likely is a way to do this with ppx (which I have not mastered nor explored in depth) this might also verge into XY problem territory depending on what you're ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: @Chris I'm sorry for the confusion; There was a typo while translating my code in to a MWE: `aug` should be a recursive data type using itself, not `orig`. In such case, isn't `type aug = Aug of int * orig` not viable?

Comment: Suggest rewriting `gen_dat` as `let gen_dat () = _cnt := !_cnt + 1; !_cnt`. The local let binding is unnecessary.

Comment: @Chris Using local let binding is a matter of taste, IMO. But the `gen_dat` part is simply for demonstration. The point of my question is about reducing boilerplate code that transforms `orig`-like type to multiple `aug`-like types.

Comment: I’m sure someone will come up with relevant PPX tools. In the meantime, if you have the possibility to modify the `orig` type, perhaps you could make it a type constructor that takes the `dat` type as a parameter. Then you’d just have to write a recursive function `map_dat : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a aug -> 'b aug` (or have it generated by PPX magic), which might be a useful factorization?

Comment: @Maëlan You mean `map_dat : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a orig -> 'b aug`, right? It would be nice if I could do it, but it does not make sense in my usecase as `aug` is a result of attaching metadata to `orig` which is unknown prior to post-processing. Maybe now is an appropriate time to invest time and learn ppx..

Comment: I really meant `'a aug -> 'b aug`. You’d have only one inductive type, and you’d define `orig` as `unit aug`.

Comment: @Maëlan Oh, that would work nice in simple instances of this problem!